# $G/H_1 = G/H_2$ implies $H_1 = H_2$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H_1, H_2$ subgroups such that $G/H_1 = G/H_2$.
I think $H_1$ has to be isomorphic to $H_2$, but must it be equal?

Comment: The only coset that is a subgroup in $G/N$ is $N$.

Comment: If $G/H_1 = G/H_2$ means equality in terms of actual cosets of $G$, then see Thorgott's answer. If $G/H_1 = G/H_2$ denotes isomorphism, then no $H_1$ need not be the same as $H_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G/H_1$ is the set of cosets of $H_1$ in $G$. Out of these cosets, there is precisely one containing the identity element of $G$, namely $H_1$ itself. So if $G/H_1=G/H_2$, then the unique element of this set containing the identity of $G$ is $H_1=H_2$.